# Timestamp in and out of lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, timestamp

I'm trying two approaches to the same thing. This one works fine:

```
early_finishers = df[pd.to_datetime(df['assignment1_submission']) < '2016']
```

This one gives me the error *TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'*:

```
df['early'] = df['assignment1_submission'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) < '2016')
```

Am I doing something wrong with the lambda function that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would just wrap your '2016' string in a pd.to_datetime() as well:

```
df['early'] = df['assignment1_submission'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) < pd.to_datetime('2016'))
```

I can't say why your first approach works...but my guess is that with a '<' operand, pandas would try to convert the dates on the left of '<' and the strings on the right of '<' all to ints , thus making this work in your pandas mask